# Is there documentation available for Thinlet 0.75?

Tags: java, user-interface, documentation

I've recently downloaded Thinlet 0.75 (http://www.thinlet.com/index.html) and was wondering if anyone knew of decent documentation for this framework?

The tutorials/examples I have found online seem to refer to an older version of Thinlet as the code/xml is no longer applicable.  The only semblance of documentation within the zip file is javadoc with no actual written documentation in it and a convoluted demo without any real explanation of anything.

Comment: wow your question is already number one for thinlet 0.75 documentation good luck finding what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point I suspect you need to contact the author Robert Bajzat directory (the copyright link has a link to his mail address). There may not be documentation written yet (one reason it is 0.75).  If you have the source code for the demo applet then you can at least see it run and see the code at the same time.